# Change application.properties for each thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I've developed an application in spring that is steered by multiple properties, that are taken from application.properties. So far it worked great, but now I'm trying to adjust these properties, so the program is more efficient. For that i need to search through pretty huge space and then evaluate how full run of a program works for given properties set. As long as it's pretty time consuming, and evaluations are not dependent of each other, I thought that i can make some computations parallel. Here comes the problem - for needs of evaluation, I have to change properties in application.properties during runtime. For one thread and synchronous execution it works ok, but I guess that there is only one instance of properties, so changing them for one thread, will also change them for other threads (which are also changing these propeties).

Do you know any way to set properties only in context of one thread? I know, that properties may be passed to a method by a parameter, but i would like to avoid that.

Comment: Not sure what you means? Can you write some dummy code for elaborating what you really want to achieve?

Comment: Are you asking how to make Spring provide different properties for each thread, so it works with `@Value` annotations?